# What do each of PuTTY's text colours represent?

Tags: linux, putty

For example what is white text on a pink background?
Or white text on a red background?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Here](http://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2008-June/msg00174.html)

- Executable files: Green

  - Normal file : Normal
  - Directory: Blue
  - Symbolic link : Cyan
  - Pipe: Yellow
  - Socket: Magenta
  - Block device driver: Bold yellow foreground, with black background
  - Character device driver: Bold yellow foreground, with black
    background
  - Orphaned syminks : Blinking Bold white with red background
  - Missing links ( … and the files they point to) : Blinking Bold
    white with red background
  - Archives or compressed : Red (.tar, .gz, .zip, .rpm)
  - Image files : Magenta (.jpg, gif, bmp, png, tif)